# $(#id).html(content) function to set content to the next column

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML code:

```
  <div class="row margin-top-3">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    <h2>NFTs</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-bordered">
     <thead>
      <tr>
      <th id = "NFTID">NFT ID</th>
      <th id = "NFTNAME">NFT Name</th>
      <th id = "NFTCREATOR">Creator</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="NFT-rows">
     </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

The following three functions populate the table by column.
The problem is that the third function overwrites the second column instead of the third column.
Also, adding a fourth function will again overwrite the second column.

So, how can I re-write the $(#id).html(content) part to make it populate the next column instead of the second?

```
 setupNFTRows: function() {
  console.log("setupNFTrows NFT Array = " + JSON.stringify(NFTs));
  console.log("NFT = " + Object.keys(NFTs))
  Object.keys(NFTs).forEach(function (NFT) { 
    console.log("inside setupNFTrows");
   $("#NFT-rows").append("<tr><td>" + "NFT_ID_" + NFT + "</td><td id='" + NFTs[NFT] + "'></td></tr>");
  });
 },

 populateNFTNames: function() {
  console.log("inside populateNFTNames")
  let NFTIDs = Object.keys(NFTs);
  console.log("NFTIDs = " + NFTIDs)
  for(var i=0; i < NFTIDs.length; i++) {
    let nftid = NFTIDs[i];
    NFTContract.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
      contractInstance.getNFTname.call(nftid).then(function(v) {
        $("#" + NFTs[nftid]).html(v.toString());
      })
    })
  }
 },

 populateCreators: function() {
  let NFTIDs = Object.keys(NFTs);
  for(var i=0; i < NFTIDs.length; i++) {
    let nftid = NFTIDs[i];
    NFTContract.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
      contractInstance.getCreator.call(nftid).then(function(v) {
       $("#" + NFTs[nftid]).html(v.toString());
      })
    })
  }
 },
```

Comment: why do you have two columns in your appended row, but your table has 3 headings? Why are you writing two different things to one column?

Answer (score 2):

This is because data tables are populated a row at a time, not a column at a time. The best way to approach this would be to zip your data together into a cohesive set to fill the rows:

```
    const getNFTNames = (id) => {
      NFTContract.deployed().then(contractInstance => {
        contractInstance.getNFTname.call(nftid).then(v => {
          return v.toString();
        });
      });
    };

    const getCreators = (id) => {
      NFTContract.deployed().then(contractInstance => {
        contractInstance.getCreator.call(nftid).then(v => {
          return v.toString();
        });
      });
    };

    const setupNFTRows = () => {
      Object.keys(NFTs).forEach(id => {
       $("#NFT-rows").append(
        `<tr id='NFT_ID_${id}'>
          <td>NFT_ID_${id}</td>
          <td>${getNFTNames(id)}</td>
          <td>${getCreators(id)}</td>
         </tr>`);
      });
    };
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help.
I'm not so good with javascript, but I think my functions are declared as property.

so, i have to declare it in a format like this: "getNFTNames:function(nftid)"
however, this is returning an error, "getNFTNames is not defined"
Do you know how to go around resolving  this?

Comment: I would assume you did not copy them in the order presented. In vanilla JavaScript, execution can only happen on objects that currently exist. In this case, the last function declared should be the one calling the others inside of it. You also may have to break the chain of commas and use a semicolon to declare the end of the function previous to setupNFTRows for all to be recognized.